# How to ensure we listen to a child process' events before they occur?

Tags: node.js, spawn

Here is some node.js code that spawns a linux `ls` command and prompts its result

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-l']);

let content = "";
ls.stdout.on('data', function(chunk){
    content += chunk.toString();
});

ls.stdout.on('end', function(){
    console.log(content);
});
```

This works well. However, the `ls` command is launched asynchronously, completely separated from the main nodeJs thread. My concern is that the `data` and `end` events on the process' `stdout` may have occurred *before* I attached event listeners.

Is there a way to attach event listeners before starting that sub-process ?

**Note :** I don't think I can wrap a Promise around the `spawn` function to make this work, as it would rely on events to be properly catched to trigger success/failure (leading back to the problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem here.

Readable streams (since node v0.10) have a (limited) internal buffer that stores data until you read from the stream. If the internal buffer fills up, the backpressure mechanism will kick in, causing the stream to stop reading data from its source.

Once you call `.read()` or add a `data` event handler, the internal buffer will start to drain and will then start reading from its source again.

Comment: I totally agree on that. Declared streams are in a "blocking mode" until you start listening to them. But wouldn't the `data` event be emitted anyway, to announce that there is indeed data in the buffer ? Or do you mean that this event will be emitted only as soon as there is at least one dedicated event listener to the stream ?

Comment: `data` events are not emitted unless the stream is flowing. Adding a `data` event handler implicitly makes the stream start flowing. If you also want to know if the stream has data (it's readable), you could listen for the `readable` event on the stream.

Comment: I bet this was clearly indicated in the API... Many thanks !